# Flutter: How can I make a stream produce objects in periodic manner?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-stream

I have this function that aims at producing a `Quote` object after every 5 seconds.

```dart
Stream<Quote> quotesStream(Realm populatedRealm) async* {
  List<Quote> quotes = populatedRealm.all<Quote>().toList();

  for (Quote aQuote in quotes) {
    // Wait for 5 seconds before yielding the next quote.
    Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    print(aQuote.quote); // Just to see what is going on.
    yield aQuote;
  }
}
```

It is then called in a `StreamBuilder` within a `StatelessWidget` like this.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Quote initialQuote = Quote('Nothing', 'none', '0', 'nothing');
  final String title;

  HomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // The stream
  final Stream<Quote> newQuotesStream = quotesStream(RealmProvider.realm);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<QuotesBloc, QuotesState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state.quotesFetchingStatus == QuotesFetchingStatus.initial) {
              context.read<QuotesBloc>().add(const FetchingQuotes());
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (state.quotesFetchingStatus == QuotesFetchingStatus.success) {
              return StreamBuilder<Quote>(
                stream: newQuotesStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    Quote q = snapshot.data!;
                    return QuoteWidget(quote: q);
                  } else {
                    return QuoteWidget(quote: initialQuote);
                  }
                },
              );
            } else {
              return QuoteWidget(quote: initialQuote);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Apparently, all the quotes are streamed simultaneously; therefore, the `QuoteWidget` shows only the last quote.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Adding `await` to `Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));` will solve your issue.

Comment: "How can I make a stream produce objects in periodic manner?" check `Stream.periodic` constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `await` before `Future<void>.delayed` in `quotesStream` will fix your issue.

```dart
Stream<Quote> quotesStream(Realm populatedRealm) async* {
  List<Quote> quotes = populatedRealm.all<Quote>().toList();

  for (Quote aQuote in quotes) {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    print(aQuote.quote);
    yield aQuote;
  }
}
```

Also, as [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) said you can alternatively use `Stream.periodic` instead of `Future.delayed` like this:

```dart
Stream<Quote?> quotesStream(Realm populatedRealm) {
  List<Quote> quotes = populatedRealm.all<Quote>().toList();

  return Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (int index) {
    if (index < quotes.length) {
      Quote aQuote = quotes[index];

      print(aQuote.quote);
      return aQuote;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }).takeWhile((quote) => quote != null);
}
```